# Sum numbers that are positive which is less than n

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun sum (n) 
  (if (n<0) 0 n-1) ;; if n<0, add 0. Else add the next smallest.
  (sum (n-1)))
```

So far I come out with something like this but I am not sure how do I declare a variable to store the sum that I would like to return.

Comment: Do you mean `(sum 4)` -> `10` or `(sum 4)` -> `6`? in other words, do you need to sum the integers _strictly less_ than `n` or the integers _not greater_ than `n`?

Comment: The latter `(sum 4) -> 6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: zerop > minusp to check for negative numbers, fixed to fit OPs question

Was some time ago I used Lisp but if I recall right the last evaluation gets returned. A recursive solution to your problem would look like this:

```
 (defun sum (n)  
    (if (<= n 0) 0 ;;if n is less or equal than 0 return 0
        (+ (- n 1) (sum (- n 1))))) ;; else add (n-1) to sum of (n-1)
```

Comment: This works. Just that I would need to change `(+ n (sum (- n 1)))` to `(+ (- n 1) (sum (- n 1)))` instead as it is all numbers less than `n` as per question.

Comment: If you expect `sum` to never be called with negative numbers, at least use an `assert` to prevent accidental infinite recursion ;-)

Comment: You solved the problem `0 + 1 + 2 +  ... + n` while the OP has the problem `0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (n-1)`

Comment: The intermediate results of recursive calls to `sum` must be kept temporarily in memory to compute intermediate sums. This prevents tail-call optimization and makes the function use 0(n) space. For large enough values of `n`, this will result in a stack overflow error. You might want to use an accumulator instead, though for learning purposes this is arguably not much a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you are implementing [1+2+...+m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) for *m = n-1*, which admits a simple formula:

```
(lambda (n)
  ;; You could inject n-1 on the formula to get n.(n-1)/2
  ;; (like in Vatine's answer), but here I just decrement 
  ;; the input  to show how to modify the local variable 
  ;; and reuse the formula linked above to sum up-to m.
  (decf n) 
  (if (minusp n) 
    0 
    (/ (* n (1+ n)) 2)))
```

An iterative version would work too, there is no need go recursive when doing simple loops:

```
(lambda (n) (loop :for x :below n :sum x))
```

Regarding your code:

- Space matters<sup>**1**</sup>: `n<0` is read as a symbol of name "N<0" (upcased by default). The same goes for `n-1` which is a symbol named "N-1".
- `(n<0)` will attempt to run the function named `n<0`. The same goes for `(n-1)`.
- Comparison: you can use [`(minusp n)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_minusp.htm) or `(< n 0)`.
- Decrement: you can use [`(1- n)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_1pl_1_.htm) or `(- n 1)`.

If what you wrote was correctly written, like this:

```
(defun sum (n) 
  (if (< n 0) 0 (- n 1)) 
  (sum (- n 1)))
```

... there would still be issues:

- You expect your `(n-1)` to actually decrement `n` but here the `if` only compute a value without doing side-effects.
- You unconditionally call `(sum (n-1))`, which means: infinite recursion. The value returned by the preceding `if` is always ignored.

---

**1**: For details, look at *constituent* and *terminating* characters: [2.1.4 Character Syntax Types](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_ad.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In Lisp, all comparator functions are just that, functions, so it needs to be `(< n 0)` and `(- n 1)` (or, more succinct, `(1- n)`).

You don't need to keep an intermediate value, you can simply add things up as you go. However, this is complicated by the fact that you are summing to "less than n", not "to n", so you need to use a helper function, if you want to do this recursively.

Even better, if you peruse the standard (easily available on-line, as [the Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://clhs.lisp.se/), you will sooner or later come across the chapter on iteration, where the `loop` facility does everything you want.

So if I needed to do this, I would do one of:

```
(defun my-sum (n)
   (/ (* n (1- n)) 2))
```

or

```
(defun my-sum (n)
   (loop for i below n
         sum i))
```

If I absolutely needed to make it recursive, I would use something like:

```
(defun my-sum (n)
   (labels ((sum-inner (i)
              (if (< i 1)
                0
                (+ i (sum-inner (1- i))))))
     (sum-inner (1- n))))
```

This is (almost) identical to defining a global function called `sum-inner`, which may be preferable for debugging purposes. However, since it is very unlikely that `sum-inner` would have any other use, I made it local.